# vue gallery adding loading spinner

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gallery, nuxt.js, image-gallery

I created a gallery using Vue, Nuxt.

The full code of my gallery you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/MartCube/vueGallery),

and you can see a live demo here [vue gallery demo](https://vue-gallery.netlify.com/)

Most of the logic is in the vue-lighbox component.

```js
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  thumbnails: {
   type: Array,
   required: true,
  },
  images: {
   type: Array,
   required: true,
  },
  thumbnailPath: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
  },
  imagePath: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
  },
 },
 data() {
  return {
   visible: false,
   currentImage: 0,
  }
 },
 methods: {
  Toggle(index) {
   this.currentImage = index
   this.visible = !this.visible
  },
  Next() {
   if (this.currentImage < this.images.length - 1) {
    this.currentImage++
   } else {
    this.currentImage = 0
   }
  },
  Prev() {
   if (this.currentImage > 0) {
    this.currentImage--
   } else {
    this.currentImage = this.images.length - 1
   }
  },
  
 
 },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="thumb_container">
    <div v-for="(thumbnail, index) in thumbnails" :key="thumbnail" class="thumbnail" @click="Toggle(index)">
      <img :src="thumbnailPath + thumbnail" />
      <div class="plus">
        <i class="icon icon-plus" />
      </div>
      <div class="color-overlay"></div>
    </div>


    <div v-if="visible" class="lightbox">
      <i class="icon-cancel" @click="Toggle()" />
      <i class="icon-left" @click="Prev()" />
      <i class="icon-right" @click="Next()" />
      <img :key="currentImage" :src="imagePath + [currentImage + 1] +'.jpg'" />
    </div>
  
 </div>
</template>
```

A quick break down of my component:

I have small thumbnail images and big images.
The thumbnail images are displayed with for loop. Whenever I click at some of the thumbnails the corresponding big image appears.

The gallery is working fine as intended, however, I have a problem with loading the photos from user experience aspect. So I need to implement a loading spinner while the big image is loading.

I really don't know the right approach to this. Does someone have an example to share or some hint to give me?

How can I check when a fallowing image is loaded?

Comment: You can either load big images before showing them (but the page load will be heavier) or add an event listener on each image when you click the previous and next buttons (`load` event) https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/load

Answer (score 2):

You can use vue's `v-on:load` directive to determine whether to show an image or a spinner. In my app I've made this into a custom component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <img :src="src"
        :alt="alt"
        @load="onLoaded"
        @error="onError"
        v-show="loaded && !error"
        key="image"/>
      <spinner-component v-show="loaded == false || error"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
export default {
  mounted() {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      error: false
    }
  },
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String
    },
    alt: {},
    width: {},
    height: {}
  },
  computed: {
    style({ width, height }) {
      return {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        objectFit: "contain"
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onLoaded() {
      this.loaded = true;
    },
    onError() {
      this.error = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. v-on:load is a custom directive ? 
shouldn't the directive be registered somewhere ? 
I would appreciate if you could explain a little bit more.

Comment: It's not a custom directive. It's a Vue directive - you can use it as long as you're using Vue.js

Comment: Maybe @CathyHa wants to say that v-on is a directive. But "load" it is event. You can use above as example and make is lazy loading images. Or make wrapper with spinner and lazy loading for any images, but it's a little harder.

Comment: Yes apologies - that is what I mean.